# how to authenticate mvc application by another mvc application (diffrent domain)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I Have mvc application under this address www.sample1.com and it's useing sso to to authenticate user so far so good 
my question is how can I use that authenticated user for another mvc applicathion under separate domain www.sample2.com

it means second mvc application should follow first one if user is authenticated there it will be authenticated in second one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121278/single-sign-on-sso-across-different-domains-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up one of the sites (or a third) as the SSO authority. Then any other sites must redirect the user to that one for logging in/out. The primary authentication cookie will be set on that SSO domain, and then it will need to pass a token back to the originating site to "authorize" the user there. This is not trivial and takes a lot of work to implement properly. Checkout [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic) for a good primer.

Comment: Umm.. yeah it is. Perhaps there's something going on with your internet connection?