# How to implement Single Sign On in java project?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

As the question says, I am trying to implement Single Sign On for my java project. I am using tomcat 8. But I don't have any idea how to implement this. When user enter Username and Password for first time and he/she close the window without logout from application. Then, when user open application again then user should not enter username and password again or user should be logged in. It would be great and really helpful if someone guide me for the same.

Comment: we use a database for that, store a session variable, unique token on log in which is use in the session thereafter

Comment: @juju could you please explain it more because I know session variable then how can I use it for single sign on. :)

Comment: I would recommend doing a lot of reading, have included some links in the answer but, there's no simple, easy answer, you'll have to build it according to your specs, based on good knowledge of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

seems like there is already answer here;

[How to Implement SSO on existing tomcat web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950023/how-to-implement-sso-on-existing-tomcat-web-application)

but some further reading;

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-integrate-sso-into-your-application

[Single Sign On [SSO] across different domains using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121278/single-sign-on-sso-across-different-domains-using-java)

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links.